# Is Basic Regular Expression same as pathname expansion in shell?

Tags: linux, command

I'm learning about regular expression, and they are divided into basic and extended.

Basic Regular Expression(BRE) uses meta-character `[ ] ^ $ . *`.

It's works on `grep` command well. But, when we use `ls`, `echo` or something else command, it works well, too.(For example, `ls -al [abc]*.txt`)

But, when I learn section about pathname expansion, it uses BRE's metacharcter.

So, I think they are same. Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pathname expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13_03) doesn't hold any special meaning for `^`, `$`, or `.`.

1. `*` in a BRE matches zero or more repetitions of the preceding character or group (so `a*` →  , `a`, `aa`, `aaa`, …). `*` in pathname expansion matches any string, independent of the previous character (so `a*` → `a`, `ab`, `a !!! and any ?? string whatsoever`, … - *note*: it doesn't match the empty string, which the `a*` BRE does). Similarly for `?`.
2. Negation in `[]` is via a leading `^` in BRE and a leading `!` in pathname expansion.
3. `.` matches any character in BRE, whereas `.` has no special significance in a pathname *pattern*. It does have significance in what is
   *matched*, but not in the pattern itself.

Beyond some superficial similarities, they are very different. Some things are possible in BREs and impossible in pathname matching (for example, try matching a filename composed only of `a`s).

Comment: I confirm `$`, `.` have no special meaning above pathname expansion. But, still works `^` character. When I use `ls -al  [^ab]abc.txt`, it shows me about `kabc.txt`

Comment: @A.Cho According to POSIX: "A bracket expression starting with an unquoted circumflex character produces unspecified results" - so it leaves some room for the shell implementer to interpret it differently, and your shell supports it for negation in `[]`. It isn't necessarily true for all compliant shells. Bash does, dash doesn't.

Comment: @A.Cho: The point the muru is trying to make is that pathname expansion patterns (a.k.a. wildcards or globs) are automatically *anchored* at the beginning and the end.  For example, if you `grep` for `foo`, you may find `catfood`, and if you `grep` for `foo.*bar`, you may find `catfood at bargain prices`.  To find only `foo` you need to `grep` for `^foo$`; to find only `foo123%bar`, etc., you need to `grep` for `^foo.*bar$`.  But a wildcard of `foo*bar` ***doesn't*** match a file called `catfood_bargain`, so you don't need to do `ls -al ^foo*bar$`.